# Show do I display this dialog when GPS location is not available

Tags: android, performance, gps

[image: olacabs dialog]

This dialog comes when my GPS location is not available. In android we can't change GPS state from activity but by this dialog we can change it from activity itself. I tried many forums but didn't get any answer.

Can someone help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean this (saw it in another question)? startActivity(new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));

Comment: I think this is some default dialog available fused location api but somehow I am not able to find  it

Answer (score 0):

Usually i proceed like folowing:

```
//check if GPS is active - show dialog
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
if(!manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )){
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alert.setTitle(TITLE_ACTIVE_GPS);
                        alert.setMessage(YOUR_MESSAGE);
                        alert.setPositiveButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();}
                        });
                        alert.setNegativeButton("Go to Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent I = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(I);  
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog al_gps = alert.create();
                        al_gps.show();
                    }else{
                        //GPS enabled
                    }
```

Tapping on `Go to Settings`, the users goes to the device locations settings an he can turn on the `GPS`.

The main function of this dialog is the intent: `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS`.

You can use also a custom dialog, just use the correct intent.